# Android Connection with physical device

Tags: android, connection, port

I'm getting an error while connecting my application to my phone:

[image]

I have searched for this error so many times but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: You should tell which error you have. And after that what it has to do with programming.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to localhost?

Comment: yeah, I'm using a local host. Actually, I want to run my Android application on my phone via a USB cable. Whenever I'm opening my application and try to login into the app the error occurred as I showed in the picture.

Comment: Can anyone help me out?